# Ruby on rails multiple unique columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `Users` table with `id, user_name, email, password` columns, by default, `id` is primary key, then I set `user_name` and `email` are uniques. I don't know if multiple unique columns will guarantee the value in each column not duplicate or the value of unique columns together not duplicate? I mean, which case of followings is right?

Comment: `UNIQUE INDEX` guarantees that combination of data in all columns included is unique. If you have an index with single column it means that this column will have unique values. If you have an index with multiple columns it means that combination of values in those columns will be unique.

Comment: It is if author is using RoR validations. Which he didn't stated.
And if that's the case - each column separately will be unique. Not their combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two options here:

**Set uniqueness of each column individually**

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

The behaviour is best explained with *examples*

```
| id | name |   email   |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––|
| 1  | Dave |  d@g.com  |
| 2  | Dave |  d2@g.com | # invalid, as Dave is a duplicate
| 3  | Mary |  m@g.com  | # valid, both values are unique
```

**Set uniqueness as a scope**

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :name }
```

*Examples*

```
| id | name |   email   |
|–––––––––––––––––––––––|
| 1  | Dave |  d@g.com  |
| 2  | Dave |  d2@g.com | # valid, as the combination of Dave & d2@g.com is unique
| 3  | Mary |  m@g.com  | # valid, both values are unique
| 4  | Mary |  m@g.com  | # invalid, as the combination already exists
```

Comment: The answer is very solid with minor detail I wish you could just to give that 100% guide on how to use the `scope` option.  You could set the `scope` option with a single column (as your 2nd example suggest). The other way is to set an array of additional columns if the unique constrain should be more than 2 columns. Example that you could show `validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: [:name, :other_col] }`. Besides that, the answer is solid